# Can't get my divs to align properly

Tags: css, html

So, I am trying to get these divs to lie next to each other, under the nav menu in the format

1 2
3 4

For some reason, all I can get it to do is so the heading for the RHS (div "righthead")  is inline with the main body from the LHS (div "main"), if that makes sense...

Here is the code, please help! [I haven't explained it very well, so do ask for clarification if needed] - I am including all the code for the rest of it as well just in case that is affecting it.

```
<style type="text/css">

.hmenu{ width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  }

.hmenu ul{ margin: 0; padding: 0; font: bold 12px Verdana; list-style-type: none; }

.hmenu li{ display: inline; margin: 0; }

.hmenu li a{ float: left; display: block; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; padding: 7px 8px;  border-right: 1px solid white;  color: white; background: #D3D3D3;  }

.hmenu li a:visited{ color: white; }

.hmenu li a:hover, .hmenu li.selected a{ background: #A9A9A9; color:
#008B8B; }

body { font-family: "Verdana", Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;  }

div#container { position: relative; width: 849px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; }

#header{ width: 100%; background: blue;  border-bottom: 1px solid black; }


#mainhead{ background: #D3D3D3; clear: both; width: 634px; color: white; border-top: 4px solid white; font: 18px Verdana; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 8px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; }

#main{ background: #F2F2F2; width: 642px;  height: 800px;  padding-left: 7px; position: absolute; border-right: 1px; float: left; }

#righthead{ float: right; clear: both; background: #D3D3D3; color: white; font: 18px Verdana; width: 191px; padding-left: 7px;   height: 30px; border-left: 1px solid white; }

#right{ clear: both; float: right; background: black; width: 191px;  height: 800px;  padding-left: 7px; border-right: 1px; }



</style>
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Black Kite - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bk.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">

<!-- header --></div>

<div id="container">

<div class="hmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- hmenu --></div>

<div id="mainhead">
About Us
<!-- mainhead --></div>

<div id="righthead">
heading
<!-- righthead --></div>

<div id="main">
<p>some text here. yey. </p>
<!-- main --></div>

<div id="right">
<p>some other here. yey. </p>
<!-- right --></div>

<!-- container --></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copying that into jsfiddle didn't really give me anything to work off, either explain a bit better or give a working jsfiddle with an image of what yuo want so we can work towards it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.hmenu{ width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid black; height: 30px;  }

#mainhead{ position: absolute; background: #D3D3D3; width: 634px; color: white; border-top: 4px solid white; font: 18px Verdana; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 8px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; }

#main{ background: #F2F2F2; width: 642px;  height: 800px;  padding-left: 7px; border-right: 1px; float: left; }

#righthead{ float: right; background: #D3D3D3; color: white; font: 18px Verdana; width: 191px; padding-left: 7px;   height: 30px; border-left: 1px solid white; }

#right{ float: right; background: black; width: 191px;  height: 800px;  padding-left: 7px; border-right: 1px; }
```

Added height to .hmenu, absolute positioning to #mainhead, and removed the clear: boths. Is this what you had in mind?

http://jsfiddle.net/WPHxj/

Comment: That kind of worked - it looked perfect in jsfiddle, but for some reason when i put it into my code, my menu was covered up and I don't understand why. I like this solution, any chance you can give me a hand in trying to work out why the menu was covered up...? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I might have left out a step or something. Sorry about that. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely has to do with the position attribute. Try setting the div's of your 4 sections to `position: relative`. Then you should be able to position it how you like. If it still not quite right, put them inside of a larger content div, set it to a certain width so that only two of the divs can fit next to each other within it. Then set all their float attributes to `float:left`.

I didn't take the time to create my own jsfiddle. If this doesn't work quite right put one up so I can actually mess with the code. If you want to learn by trial and error, position attribute and floats are your likely suspect. Good Luck!

Comment: This worked - fiddled around a bit and it worked ish, but now I have some random symbols in the top right corner... I have never used jsfiddle (hadn't even heard of it) but I will try and give it a go in a sec and post it here)